# Flask file upload , The method is not allowed for the requested URL

Tags: python, file, flask, upload

```
I am trying to upload file. the abnormal is 'The method is not allowed for the requested URL' after run .  However my code is request methods is 'POST'
```

This is my html:

```
<form action="" enctype='multipart/form-data' method="POST">
<span class="btn btn-info" id="import">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    </span>input type="submit" value="upload" id="submit">
```

This is my api code:

```
@api.route('/upload', methods=['POST','GET'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        upload_path = os.path.join(APP_STATIC_TXT, secure_filename(file.filename))
        file.save(upload_path)
        return redirect(url_for('/'))
```

This run result:

> INFO: werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [14/Dec/2017 16:26:42] "POST
>   /api/v1.0/upload HTTP/1.1" 400 
>   - INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [14/Dec/2017 16:26:42] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 - INFO:werkzeug: * Detected change in
>   '/home/python/Desktop/VCG/vcg/api_1_0/test01.py', reloading

This is web html :

```
Method Not Allowed
```

The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

Comment: Please include the code here and properly format your question

Answer (score 1):

In your `form` `action` attribute using the `current view url`. Please change that to `url_for('upload')`

Comment: After change that to /upload :   still not well, abnormal is  ERROR:werkzeug:Error on request: and File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 412, in send_header and self.wfile.write("%s: %s\r\n" % (keyword, value))  and IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe.

Comment: Can you able to print `file` ?

Comment: can not print file

Comment: Can you print `request.files` after the `if request.method == 'POST'` ?

Comment: This is print content: ImmutableMultiDict([])